# turning a list from a loop iteration to a df in pyhon

Tags: python, pandas

I have some file which I am running a loop over all file and doing some calculations. I would like to get a new df with the name of the files on the row side and the calculated value per each file in the correct row.

the code is:

```
results = []
file_name = '{}'
for file in folder:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_name.format(file))
    print("reading  file ", file)
    results.append(df['old_calc'])#this is the data i want to save to the new df and I need it .sum()
```

the above code doesn't work as expected as it is giving me:

```
     old calc  old calc  old calc  old calc  old calc  old calc  old calc
4           0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0   
5           0.0         0.0         0.0        59.0         0.0         0.0   
6           0.0         0.0        58.4         0.0         0.0         0.0   
7           0.0         0.0         8.4       -79.1         0.0         0.0   
8           0.0         0.0       120.9         0.0         0.0         0.0
```

The expected result will be a new df named results:

```
file1  0
file2  0
file3  187.7
file4  20.1
file5  0
```

thanks for the help

Comment: Can you include a sample of one dataframe

Comment: I think it should be **df['old_calc'].sum()** and you are doing **.append(df['old_calc']).sum()**

Comment: @ManishSaraswat, correct. I changed it but ye i get a list of results [0,0,187.7,20,1,0] and not a df with the columns of 1. file 2. old calc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way you can extract the data you need:

```
dfs = {file: pd.read_csv(file) for file in folder}
result_dict = {k: v['old_calc'].sum() for k, v in dfs.items()}

result_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result_dict, orient='index')
```

Comment: `dfs` produces a dictionary of filename -> dataframe. `result_dict` is a dictionary of filename -> sums. `result_df` produces a dataframe from the dictionary.

Comment: I still didn't understand how to apply this in my code. sorry. dfs is something i already have with df. and I don't understand the use of v here